# Memory used to store DOM object

Tags: python, dom

I have the following statement in my code where the file myxml is 10MB size.
dom1 = minidom.parse(myxml)

Here, the parse statement goes through the XML and generates the tree and this tree in turn is stored in memory.So, I want to find just how much memory dom1 is holding?

1058.891 MiB dom1 = minidom.parse(myxml)
I used a memory profile 'memory_profiler and it says 1gb usage for that particular statement.However,I want to know the split of how much memory was consumed to convert to a tree and how much memory is used in storing the tree?

Also, I have python 2.4 running and cannot upgrade to use latest packages due to unavoidable reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This is more difficult because you are on such an old version (don't have access to test on that version).

You can try this snippet from ActiveState: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546530-size-of-python-objects-revised/

There is also Pympler. It is only tested with Python 2.5 however: https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/asizeof.html

However I would strongly suggesting upgrading.